# l_ply Confused About how to Pass Variables Through to Function

Tags: r, plyr

I'm sure this must have been answered somewhere, so; if you have a pointer to an answer that helps please let me know... ;o)

I have a number of fairly sizeable processing tasks (mainly multi-label text classifiers) which read in large volumes of files, do stuff with that, output a result then move on to the next.

I have this working neatly sequentially but wanted to parallelise things.

By way of a really basic example...

```
require(plyr)
fileDir   <- "/Users/barneyc/sourceFiles"
outputDir <- "/Users/barneyc/outputFiles"
files <- as.list(list.files(full.names=TRUE,recursive=FALSE,pattern=".csv"))

l_ply(files, function(x){
                          print(x)

                          #change to dir containing source files
                          setwd(fileDir)

                          # read file
                          content <- read.csv(file=x,header=TRUE)

                          # change directory to output
                          setwd(outputDir)

                          # append the itemID from CSV file to 
                          write.table(content$itemID,file="ids.csv", append = TRUE, sep=",", row.names=FALSE,col.names=TRUE) 

              }, .parallel=FALSE )
```

Will iterate through all the files in directory `fileDir`, opening each CSV, extracting a value from the file and appending this to an output CSV held in the directory `outputDir`.    A basic example but it runs just fine to illustrate the problem.

To run this in parallel creates a problem in so far as the directory variables (`fileDir` & `outputDir`) are essentially unknown by the anonymous `function (x)`, ala...

```
require(plyr)
require(doParallel)
fileDir   <- "/Users/barneyc/sourceFiles"
outputDir <- "/Users/barneyc/outputFiles"
files <- as.list(list.files(full.names=TRUE,recursive=FALSE,pattern=".csv"))

cl<-makeCluster(4)      # make a cluster of available cores
registerDoParallel(cl)  # raise cluster

l_ply(files, function(x){
              print(x)

              #change to dir containing source files
              #setwd(fileDir)

              # read file
              content <- read.csv(file=x,header=TRUE)

              # change directory to output
              setwd(y)

              # append the itemID from CSV file to 
              write.table(content$itemID,file="ids.csv", append = TRUE, sep=",", row.names=FALSE,col.names=TRUE) 

}, .parallel=TRUE )

stopCluster()  # kill the cluster
```

Can anyone shed light on how I pass those two directory variables through to the function here?

Comment: Try passing them as arguments to the function: `l_ply(files, function(x, y, z) {...}, y = ..., z = ...)`

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to @Roland my parallel function would now be...

```
require(plyr)
require(doParallel)
fileDir   <- "/Users/barneyc/sourceFiles"
outputDir <- "/Users/barneyc/outputFiles"
files <- as.list(list.files(full.names=TRUE,recursive=FALSE,pattern=".csv"))

cl<-makeCluster(4)      # make a cluster of available cores
registerDoParallel(cl)  # raise cluster

l_ply(files, function(x,y,z){
              filename  <- x
              fileDir   <- y
              outputDir <- z

              #change to dir containing source files
              setwd(fileDir)

              # read file
              content <- read.csv(file=filename,header=TRUE)

              # change directory to output
              setwd(outputDir)

              # append the itemID from CSV file to 
              write.table(content$itemID,file="ids.csv", append = TRUE, sep=",", row.names=FALSE,col.names=TRUE) 

}, y=fileDir, z=outputDir, .parallel=TRUE )

stopCluster()  # kill the cluster
```

Comment: You could avoid this copying/renaming of parameters. Just define `function(filename, fileDir, outputDir)`.

Comment: Yeah I sussed that myself but left it example for clarity.   I now have my 16 core machine chunking through 102 classification tasks 14 at a time (save 2 cores for the OS just in case).   Nice help thanks.